# Adding fragments using for loop

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I am very new to programming an android as well. I am trying to add fragments using for loop. Lets say I would like to repeat fragment n-times.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        Fragment frag = _fragments[1];
        fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.frameForAddressFragment, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.Commit();
        }
```

I think I have to declare Fragment for every loop with new name?
Am I right?
Could some one show me right approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, I never use Xamarin, but can't you slightly change your code to this? I don't see the point of beginning a new transaction for each and every fragment. Same goes for committing.

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    Fragment frag = _fragments[1];
    fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.frameForAddressFragment, frag);
    fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.Commit();
```

Second, I don't know if it's a mistake, but you have written `Fragment frag = _fragments[1];`. I assume you meant `Fragment frag = _fragments[i];`

Third, is there any problem with your code? As a reminder, your "Resource.Id.frameForAddressFragment" is supposed to be the ID of the container in which you want to add the fragment.

Last, what do you mean by this?

> I think I have to declare Fragment for every loop with new name?

What "new name" are you talking about?