# How to programmatically add fragments in a loop to a single activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view

Since I don't know how many views I need so I have to create them dynamically. Based on my research that each fragment has to have a container, they can't share (Correct me if i'm wrong), so I need to create view container for each fragment dynamically, then I can have this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size ; i ++) {
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.disallowAddToBackStack();
ft.add(new ABCFragment(), TAG).commit();
}
```

Does anyone know how i can get this working? I'm new to android still.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/31050514/3758972

Comment: @NiteshVerma I checked, this one doesn't work for me.

Comment: that code is for xamarin , I hope you have changed it according to `java` and Android studio. Your posted code does show that you tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Define it in xml, it will work as container:-

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/R.id.container_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparents"/>
```

To get dynamic number of fragments, define different tag name for that:-

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.container_fragment, new DetailFragment(), tag.get(i));

            ft.commit();
        }
```

You can give different tag names under tag.get(i)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it seems like all my fragments are overlaying each other. My fragments are all wrap_content. Do you think if we missed something here?

Comment: Do you want all the fragments at same time in different screen

Comment: I want all fragments at the same time in the same screen.

Comment: Means you want all your fragment in a vertical manner ...that can be scrollable..or if anything else ..then please provide such drawing or somthing else so can idea what you actually want ..